# How to read H2 ResultSet from CSV, and reset cursor for second pass

Tags: java, h2

I'm writing a Java library to import data from a CSV file, and return the results as INTEGER, DECIMAL, VARCHAR and other column types, according to the results of some regular expression tests.

I therefore need to read through the `ResultSet` returned by `Csv.read()` twice; once to determine the column types and again to populate a new `SimpleResultSet` (or preferably to wrap the original `ResultSet` in a `SimpleRowSource`, so I don't have to store the table data).  I've tried calling `ResultSet.beforeFirst()`, but there are no rows available on the second pass.

```
// Create an input stream with test data.
String data =
    "name,value\n" +
    "one,1\n" +
    "two,2\n" +
    "three,3\n";
InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(data.getBytes());
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(stream);

// Read the test data into a new ResultSet.
Csv csv = new Csv();
ResultSet resultSet = csv.read(reader, null);

// Iterate over the ResultSet on first pass.
int firstPass = 0;
while (resultSet.next())
{
    // Test all values for integer, decimal etc.
    ++firstPass;
}
System.out.println("Read " + firstPass + " row(s) on first pass");

// Move the cursor to before the first row; this doesn't work!
resultSet.beforeFirst();

// Check if the cursor is before the first row; throws exception!
/* resultSet.isBeforeFirst(); */

// Iterate over the ResultSet on second pass.
int secondPass = 0;
while (resultSet.next())
{
    // Add all values to new SimpleResultSet, or wrap this code
    // in an H2 SimpleRowSource, and pass to the constructor of
    // a new SimpleResultSet.
    ++secondPass;
}
System.out.println("Read " + secondPass + " row(s) on second pass");
```

This produces the following output:

```
Read 3 row(s) on first pass
Read 0 row(s) on second pass
```

I note that `beforeFirst()` does not throw an exception, but `isBeforeFirst()` does:

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Feature not supported: null [50100-172]
```

I would appreciate any suggestions on why this doesn't work, or on another way of doing this!

**UPDATE**

Because the H2 `Csv.read()` function produces a `ResultSet` that cannot be rewound, I ended up copying the source `InputStream` as it's read on the first pass, and then replaying the resulting `byte[]` on the second pass.  This way, I can be sure of importing the same data.  Here's the helper class I wrote to do this:

```
public class CopyStream extends InputStream
{
    private final InputStream mInputStream;
    private final ByteArrayOutputStream mOutputStream;

    public CopyStream(InputStream inputStream)
    {
        // Initialise the class.
        mInputStream = inputStream;
        mOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    }

    public InputStream copy()
    {
        // Return a new input stream based on the copied data.
        byte[] buffer = mOutputStream.toByteArray();
        return new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer);
    }

    @Override
    public int read() throws IOException
    {
        // Read a byte from the input stream.
        int b = mInputStream.read();
        if (b >= 0)
        {
            // Copy the byte to the output stream.
            mOutputStream.write(b);
        }
        return b;
    }

    @Override
    public int read(byte[] buffer) throws IOException
    {
        // Read some bytes from the input stream.
        int length = mInputStream.read(buffer);
        if (length > 0)
        {
            // Copy the bytes to the output stream.
            mOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        return length;
    }

    @Override
    public int read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int length) throws IOException
    {
        // Read some bytes from the input stream.
        length = mInputStream.read(buffer, offset, length);
        if (length > 0)
        {
            // Copy the bytes to the output stream.
            mOutputStream.write(buffer, offset, length);
        }
        return length;
    }
}
```

This is used as follows:

```
Csv csv = new Csv();
CopyStream copyStream = new CopyStream(inputStream);
ResultSet resultSet1 = csv.read(new InputStreamReader(copyStream), null);
ResultSet resultSet2 = csv.read(new InputStreamReader(copyStream.copy()), null);
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to read the `ResultSet` twice. <strike>You can use the non-standard H2 command `CSVREAD` to populate the table from the file.</strike>

Alternatively, you could just create the Csv object again.

Comment: As far as I can see, `CSVREAD` provides the same functionality as the `Csv.read()` Java method, and creates only VARCHAR columns.  I'm trying to create a `ResultSet` with INTEGER, DECIMAL etc columns, so unfortunately I do need to read the data twice.  Yes I could call `Csv.read()` twice, but it seems inelegant. (-:

Comment: Hmm.  I'm currently storing the results of `Csv.read()` in a `List<Object[]>`; but if I have to call `Csv.read()` twice, it might be better to store the contents of the original file in a big `byte[]` instead.

Comment: For the curious... I ended up subclassing `InputStream`, and copying all bytes read from the source file to a `ByteArrayOutputStream`, so I could call `Csv.read()` again with the duplicated byte array (I was concerned that the underlying file might have changed in the meantime).

Comment: @HuwWalters You should post that as an answer and accept it. That will mark the question as closed and bump your solution to the top.

Comment: Will do that when I get a spare moment, and include the helper class I wrote; could be handy for other SO users.